# Equivalent to PowerBI with Azure Data Lake using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, azure, powerbi

We have a solution were we make multiple dashboards on PowerBI using Azure Data Lake in the back. Does anybody know how we can have the equivalent built using ReactJS with Azure Data Lake without exta use of APIs?

Comment: You can refer to [A new Power BI component for React is now available](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/announcing-react-power-bi/), [Tutorial: Create a Power BI visual using React](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/create-react-visual) and [Analyze data in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 by using Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/datalakestorage)